# JavaScript stop working after AJAX call

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

My javascript is getting locked after ajax call.

When the user press enter then i call my c# method to search the city that the user typed, and then show the temperature, but when the search ends, the javascript stops working. And i found out that the error is on these lines: 
                    var div = document.getElementById('rb-grid');
                    div.innerHTML = resp.responseText + div.innerHTML;

code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#search-bar').keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {

            myFunction();

        }
    });

    function myFunction() {
        var city = $('#search-bar').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("getWeatherSearch", "Index")',
            data: { city: city },
            async: false,
            complete: function (resp) {
                var div = document.getElementById('rb-grid');
                div.innerHTML = resp.responseText + div.innerHTML;
                Boxgrid.init();
            }
        });
    } });
```

HTML:

```
            <div align="center" class="div-search-bar">
                @Html.TextBox("search-bar", "", new { @class = "search-bar", placeholder = "search" })
            </div>
```

Comment: And what is `#rb-grid`? Probably a parent element, and you're replacing the `#search-bar` element with a new one ?

Comment: Unless you have a good reason to include it you should remove `async: false`.

Comment: @Andy i use async: false, because i need the value from the method

Comment: what is `Boxgrid.init()`?

Comment: @adeneo #rb-grid is where i'll add some html code that the method return to me.

Comment: `async: false` is not necessary. you will have the value from the method in the `complete` function anyway

Comment: @lante it's a js that came with my template

Comment: @lante but it does not resolve my problem

Comment: have you placed a debugger line to make sure the callback is working and where it locks up.  Also try removing the Boxgrid.init() and replace with an alert

Comment: @TMcKeown i removed boxgrid.init() and no effect.

Comment: Is `.div-search-bar` inside `#rb-grid`?

Comment: Try it like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/yqFVC/

Comment: you mean it still locks up?  i would start with just an alert in the complete event...  and add line by line..

Comment: @JasonP <ul id="rb-grid" class="rb-grid clearfix">

Comment: @adeneo after trying that code the enter press stopped working

Comment: @Vinicius I mean is your div with class `div-search-bar` that you posted inside or a child of the element with id `rb-grid`?

Comment: @JasonP rb-grid yes it is but i named it very bad...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and see if it works for you:

```
 $(function () {
     var $searchbar = $('#search-bar'),
         $grid = $('#rb-grid');

     if ($grid.length) {
         $searchbar.on('keyup', function (event) {
             if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                 myFunction();

             }
         });

         function myFunction() {
             var city = $searchbar.val();
             $.ajax({
                 url: $.grid.data('weather-url'),
                 data: { city: city }
             })
             .done(function (resp) {
                     $grid.html(resp.responseText + $grid.html());
                     Boxgrid.init();
                 }
             });
         }
     }
 });
```

Add the following as a data attribute somewhere in your html, probably on your grid:

```
 <div id='rb-grid' data-weather-url='@Url.Action("getWeatherSearch", "Index")'></div>
```

Comment: it still getting locked