# JavaScript innerHTML locking other javascripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

for some reason a innerHTML in my javascript code is locking other javascript functions, and i do not have any idea why... this is the javascript that is locking the others.

```
        var city = $('#search-bar').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Index/getWeatherSearch',
            data: { city: city },
            //async: false,
            error: function (resp) {
                alert("Error");
            },
            complete: function (resp) {
                var div = document.getElementById('rb-grid');
                div.innerHTML = resp.responseText + div.innerHTML;
            }
        });
```

Comment: 'locking' means what?

Comment: locking?? you mean stoping other jquery function cos of some errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694969/javascript-stop-working-after-ajax-call?rq=1

Comment: @CodingAnt yes, its stopping other jquery functions

Comment: Why are you using `innerHTML` in the first place? https://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: does `resp` have a `responseText` property? what does your console say?

Comment: Is this code running on a loop/keypress? What does "stopping" mean exactly?

Comment: @epascarello always when the user press enter on the texbox it will cal this js

Comment: @andrew I guess it does, because `complete` receives an jqXHR object as the first parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by locking exactly, but you are removing elements and adding them back. Better to append the new content.

```
var div = document.getElementById('rb-grid');
div.innerHTML = resp.responseText + div.innerHTML;
```

to

```
$("#rb-grid").prepend(resp.responseText);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jQuery anyways, why not use jQuery?

Use the `success` handler instead of `complete` and do:

```
$('#rb-grid').prepend(resp);
```

The problem is that by (ab)using `innerHTML` in your code, you are rebuilding the whole DOM part for that div element. All your event handlers and modifications you did to all the descendant DOM elements are lost.